# Is it possible to send custom headers from .aspx pages without using ajax

Tags: asp.net, request-headers

I need to pass the Anti CSRF token as a custo header parameter from aspx page. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: can you please share if you have tried something or currently what is happening ?

Comment: without ajax if you want to do then you can post the page with some query string and on your page load check that querystring if it exists then do you work else retrun;

Comment: Deleted my answer since the question is about sending. Requesting you to post the current code so that I will check and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are trying to write a form in your html page and you wanna submit the form with your custom header. And you don't wanna use ajax solutions like jQuery. Is that right?

### It cannot be done - AFAIK.

However you may use for example jquery (although you can do it with plain javascript) to serialize the form and send (using AJAX) while adding your custom header.